# MongoDB use array field's element to $set a new field of the document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In the database, I have documents like the following

```
Ticket {
    "eventHistory": [
        {
            "event": "CREATED",
            "timestamp": "aa-bb-cccc"
        },
        {
            "event": "ASSIGNED",
            "timestamp": "ii-jj-kkkk"
        },
        ...
        {
            "event": "CLOSED",
            "timestamp": "xx-yy-zzzz"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to add a `closedAt` field to the relevant `Ticket`s, getting the value from the `eventHistory` array's last element. The resultant document would look like the following

```
Ticket {
    "eventHistory": [
        {
            "event": "CREATED",
            "timestamp": "aa-bb-cccc"
        },
        {
            "event": "ASSIGNED",
            "timestamp": "ii-jj-kkkk"
        },
        ...
        {
            "event": "CLOSED",
            "timestamp": "xx-yy-zzzz"
        }
    ],
    "closedAt": "xx-yy-zzzz"
}
```

The following pipeline allows me to use the entire object that's present as the `eventHistory` array's last element.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
<query>,
[
    "$set": {
        "closedAt": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$eventHistory",
                -1
            ]
        }
    }
]
...
)
```

But I want to use only the `timestamp` field; not the entire object.

Please help me adjust (and/or improve) the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to fix your query is:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
<query>,
[
  {
    $set: {
      "Ticket.closedAt": {
        $last: "$Ticket.eventHistory.timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/la3MeA5eIT7)

But note that you assume that last item is a closing one. Is this necessarily the case? Otherwise you can validate it.